# Redshift large data load, executing Python function

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a large data load into Redshift table called *responses*, that consists around 450M rows. On each of the rows I perform a Python UDF that parses the user agent.

I set a distribution based on a column *question_id*, that has around 1.5M rows. Problem is that *responses are not equally distributed among questions*:

- Top 10 *questions_ids* correspond to around 60M of all the responses;
- Top 20 *questions_ids* correspond to 78M responses;

This causes a problem when I look at the Redshift portal, at the query that is executing Python function, I see that only one of the nodes (there are 4 of them) is doing most of the work.

Should I set something else to be a distribution column (setting *question_id* perfectly suits my future querying needs)?

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh, I found the problem, table from which I was reading data and applying parsing was wrongly distributed, keeping all the data in a a single slice, so that is why parsing was slow, and only one node was working.